# How do third party installer install addons in our browser?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, browser-addons

My question is how do third party installer installs addons in the browser like toolbars and able to set homepage and other browser properties??
I want to make an addon which get installed in browser in same way..
is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

In principle, installing extensions along with other software is possible. I'm describing the procedure for Windows.

The following conditions have to be met:

- You must be able to write to the HKLM registry subtree (needs Admin rights)
- The extension **must** be published on Chrome Web Store
- The machine must be able to download the extension from Web Store

If those conditions are met, you can do it according to the procedure described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry). Basically, the installer must create a registry key that will trigger Chrome to download the extension on next launch.

---

That said, **Google has [gone to great pains](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) to prevent silent installs and avoid browser settings hijack**. Such setting overrides are a weapons race and Chrome is tightening its defenses. Ask yourself whether it's *ethical* to install your extension this way.

It will probably annoy your users and will flag your extension for more meticulous checks by Google. Remember that Google can disable any extension hosted by the Web Store if it violates its policies.

Also, be mindful of the [single purpose policy](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/12/keeping-chrome-extensions-simple.html). A toolbar that also overrides search/homepage/settings will be frowned upon. At a minimum it should be separated into several extensions, at a maximum - **don't do it**.

---

An extension [can override](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override), say, a homepage, but it's very restrictive. The extension must be in the Web Store as above, and any override pages must be verified for ownership for the Web Store developer account. All in the name of security and comfort of the users.